# Como cambiar el color de los item generados en la pestaña 'MORE' en un Tab Bar controller en swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uitableviewcell

He creado un controlador `Tab bar` y cuando agrego más de 6 items se auto genera un pestaña llamada 'MORE' en el cual se listan los demás items que se agreguen.

El problema que tengo es que cuando en el `appdelegate.swift` cambio el color de todos los `tableview` a un fondo color negro, el texto de los items de la pestaña **'MORE'** se oculta porque son color negro, y no he encontrado la forma de modificar el color del texto de los item, lo único que he podido hacer es cambiar el color de los iconos de `tableview`.

La funcion que ejecuto en el appdelegae.swift para cambiar la aparaciencia de los oebjetos es la siguiente:

```
    func DarkMode() {
    let preferencesDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    if preferencesDefault.string(forKey: "modo") == "dark" {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]

        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .black
        UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .white
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .black

        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .black
```

//  Intento fallido de cambiar el color del texto de los items          UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black], for: .normal); UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .selected)

```
        //UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    } else {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.darkText]

        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
        UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .black
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .white

        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
```

[image: Así de muestra el tableview con el texto de los items oculto]

Comment: cuando cambies el color también deberías cambial el color de tu los items de la celda, lo puedes hacer ahi mismo en tu custom cell o en el delegado para eso podrías usar algo un poco mas "hardcoreado" como un bool... tal vez si muestras mas o menos como tienes tu código? esto ayuda a poder responder con mas exactitud

Comment: Hola Yan Cervantes. Añadí el código que ejecuto para cambiar la apariencia de los objetos, y un intento de cambiar el texto que no me funcionó. de ante mano muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Los items del tableView los puedes customizar desde la celda, por ejemplo la imagen,  en la clase de tu CustomCell....  myImage.tintColor = UIColor.white, y en su init... puedes cambiar el fondo de la celda... backGroundColor = .black ya que estas solo usando referencias de clase para cambiar los fondos y los colores, no recomiendo hacer eso... y en el tableView, solo agrégale un fondo como .clear,, por si usas el fondo del view con algún color, en el caso del navigationBar si es algo así como lo estas haciendo, pero ojo, si estas generando navigationBar por view, tendrías que hacerlo cada vez

Comment: y como estas pasando desde el appDelegate la configuración el compilador toma como primer config lo que le digas al appDelegate, es mejor tener en este caso un BaseViewController con las configuraciones en caso de que tengas que hacer modificaciones como lo quieres hacer